# Schedule Recreate Snapshot and Reinitialize Subscriptions - SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, maintenance, snapshot

Monthly I have to generate a new snapshot for replication and reinitialize subscriptions in SQL 2005. I would really like to automate and schedule this, but I'm not having much luck discovering how.

Not being a DBA I'm pretty much poking around blindly in there, and I definitely don't want to screw anything up. Any thoughts?

Comment: What type or replication is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if we knew what kind of replication it was & if it was a push or pull subscription.  I'm going to make some massive assumptions here & say that your using the following, which i think the the most common replication setup:

- transactional replication
- push subscription
- distributor running at the publisher

### 1. Create a schedule to create the database snapshots

If you look at the SQL Agent jobs at the distributor you should see a job that's named something like this:
 **servername-dbname-publicationname-1**  
In addition, it will be in a category called REPEL-Snapshot.

When you setup replication you would have been given an option to run the snapshot on a schedule.  If you chose to do so, you should see this under the schedules, otherwise you'll probably see a one-off schedule in there that's not enabled from the last time you ran a snapshot.  Leave this schedule alone and create another one to your liking.

### 2. Re-initalize subscriptions

This will re-initalize a publication for all subscribers.  You can create a sql agent job to run this whenever you like.  For more details [check msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189469.aspx).

```
exec sp_reinitsubscription @publication = 'publication_name', @subscriber = 'all'
```

Comment: Close on your assumptions. Good show. It wasn't schedule initially because I wanted manual control, but I didn't know (or remember) the agent thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with replication, so keep that in mind, but if you see a script button in the top left of dialogs, you can save that script and then schedule in a job.

If the script function is not available, you could resort to tracing the activity of SSMS to see what it's doing - then working through that and the documentation to create your script.